# The correct Redux/Saga pattern for pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

I have an application that uses redux for state management and sagas for async calls, and I am trying to figure out the correct structure for pagination.  I have a reducer like this:

```
function articles(
    state = {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        page: 1,
        items: []
    },
    action
) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INVALIDATE_ARTICLE':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                didInvalidate: true,
                page: 1
            })
        case 'REQUEST_ARTICLES':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isFetching: true,
                didInvalidate: false
            })
        case 'RECEIVE_ARTICLES':
            let updatedPage = 'max';
            if (action.response.result.length == 10) {
                updatedPage = state.page + 1
            };
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                categoryId: action.category,
                isFetching: false,
                didInvalidate: false,
                items: action.response.result,
                lastUpdated: action.receivedAt,
                page: updatedPage
            })
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

And the saga that calls those related actions like this:

```
function* fetchArticles(action) {
    const { domain, category, page } = action.payload;
    try {
        yield put(requestArticles(category))
        const response = yield fetch(`${domain}/url?categories=${category}&page=${page}`)
        const stories = yield response.json();
        yield all(stories.map(story => {
            return call(fetchFeaturedImage, `${url][0]}`, story)
        }))
        const normalizedData = normalize(stories, articleListSchema);
        yield put(receiveArticles(category, normalizedData))
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('error fetching articles in saga', err)
    }
}
```

Currently I am reading the redux state from the components that call the saga and passing the page in to the saga as the payload; but I am thinking this might get messy as I will eventually have to read the state to get the page from multiple different components that want to call this saga, so I am wondering if using sagas `select()` method might be the correct approach to read the redux state and get the page directly from within the saga so I don't have to worry about passing it?

Any opinions on how to correctly structure this?